# Apache Batik: How to force JSVGComponent view to update when SVG Dom modified

Tags: java, svg, batik

Using Apache Batik,

Trying to get the JSVGComponent to update (repaint) after adding a new svg element to the DOM. I know about ALWAYS_DYNAMIC, and that is set. The new element(s) are successfully added to the document, but the only way I can get the component to repaint is to resize the view. Upon resize, the new elements pop (appear) into place. I have also tried to add the elements via a Runnable using the UpdateManager and the RunnableQueue. Again, the elements are successfully added, but don't appear until the component is resized (by resizing the housing frame). I have also tried invoking the repaint via a RunQ Runnable, but that also does not work (tho the repaint is actually called).

I think I may have to actually go into the GVT bridge, but I'd sure rather not.

Help extraordinarily appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
svgCanvas.setDocument(doc);
```

It's works for an JSVGCanvas, may be it will works for you.

You can also try method :

```
setSVGDocument(doc);
```

I found this :

There are two common causes for this. The first is that the JSVGCanvas doesn’t know it’s a dynamic document. Normally Batik detects this by looking for script elements but when you modify the document from Java it can’t tell. So call `myJSVGCanvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);` before loading the document (with setURI, setDocument, setSVGDocument, etc.).

The second common reason is that the changes aren’t made in the UpdateManager ’s thread. You can run code in the UpdateManager ’s thread with the following:

```
UpdateManager um = JSVGCanvas.getUpdateManager();
um.getUpdateRunnableQueue().invokeLater(Runnable);
```

NOTE: The update manager only becomes available after the first rendering completes. You can be notified when this happens by registering a GVTTreeRendererListener.

But i don't try this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Almost same problem for me : I had to dynamically modifiy the background of boxes (polygon node).

According to MelodyBibi, it works with `setSVGDocument(doc);` but the SVG flashes during refresh. It's not very appreciable.

My (better) solution is to call 
`svgCanvas.getCanvasGraphicsNode().fireGraphicsNodeChangeCompleted();`
after modifying the DOM model using `polygonElement.setAttribute("fill", "red");` on the appropriate Node.

I also added `JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC` before the first loading of the document.

Now my SVG refreshes in realtime, without blinking.

Hoping this will help you.